# How to handle external errors when using Tonic where I must use tonic::Status?

Tags: rust, redis, tonic

I am making a Tonic-based gRPC microservice that uses the Redis client. I can't figure out an example of implicitly converting a `RedisError` into a `tonic::Status` when an asynchronous error occurs.

```rust
async fn make_transaction(
    &self,
    request: Request<TransactionRequest>,
) -> Result<Response<TransactionResponse>, Status> {
    let mut con = self.client.get_async_connection().await?;
    con.set("my_key", 42).await?;
    ...
}
```

The connection from Redis client can fail as well as the set. I would rather not use `.map_err()` since that seems to break the async.

I was thinking I need to implement the trait `From<Status>` and `From<RedisError>` but not sure how to do it. This is my attempt, but it doesn't work since Tonic wants a `tonic::Status`, not a `ApiError` struct that I made:

```rust
pub struct ApiError {}

impl From<tonic::Status> for ApiError {
    fn from(err: Status) -> ApiError {
        ApiError {  }
    }
}

impl From<RedisError> for Status {
    fn from(err: redis::RedisError) -> ApiError {
        ApiError {  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to get around this type of problem by using a custom type as a transition vessel for the original error (which is `RedisError` in your case), so something like the following might work for you as well:

```rust
pub struct ApiError {}

impl From<RedisError> for ApiError {
    fn from(err: RedisError) -> Self {
        Self { }
    }
}

impl From<ApiError> for Status {
    fn from(err: ApiError) -> Self {
        Self::internal("Failed talking to Redis")
    }
}

async fn set_key(client: ..., key: &str, value: i64) -> Result<(), ApiError> {
    let mut con = client.get_async_connection().await?;
    con.set(key, value).await?
    ...
}

async fn make_transaction(
    &self,
    request: Request<TransactionRequest>,
) -> Result<Response<TransactionResponse>, Status> {
    set_key(self.client, "my_key".into(), 42).await?
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best way, but seems to do the job.